# Change main Node version on Plesk

Tags: node.js, linux, plesk

i wrote an nodejs script wich can be only used in a higher nodejs version.
On my pc the script works fine but not on my Ubuntu with Plesk.

When i run `node -v` it will display `v8.10.0`.
The version i need is 14x.

How can i switch to a newer version on my Plesk server ?

Best regards.

Comment: I saw this post earlier but not because i want to run my script in ssh not in a plesk domain

Comment: Basically i installed now v15x but i want to activate the version now how can i do that